# Swift4 - Unexpectedly found nil - Setting Image to Button

Tags: swift, image, button

Hi guys I want to make a helper class, which sets all my pictures to my buttons. But always the picture is nil :( Where is my mistake?

class 1 (Where action happens)

```
class RandomClass {
    let imageSetter = ImageSetter()
    let mvc = MainViewController()

    func actionWhenConnected(){
    imageSetter.setButtonImages(nameOfButton: mvc.ConnectingButtonLabel, nameOfImage: "Connection/ConnectionOn", nameOfColor: .green, forStatus: .normal)
    }
}
```

This means when the function is called, the image in my MainViewController should switch to my green Connection On Picture

class 2 (Helper Class)

```
class ImageSetter{

func setButtonImages(nameOfButton:UIButton, nameOfImage:String, nameOfColor:UIColor, forStatus:UIControl.State){
    nameOfButton.setImage(UIImage(named: nameOfImage), for: forStatus)
    let origImage = UIImage(named: nameOfImage)
    let tintedImage = origImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    nameOfButton.setImage(tintedImage, for: .normal)
    nameOfButton.tintColor = nameOfColor
    }

}
```

[Assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXoS3.png)

In my MainViewController it works :(
It seems that RandomClass has no access to assets.xcassets because it doesnt find the name of the image?

SOLVED!

```
    func actionWhenConnected(){
    let mvc = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as! MainViewController
    imageSetter.setButtonImages(nameOfButton:mvc.ConnectingButtonLabel, nameOfImage: "Connection/ConnectionOff", nameOfColor: .red, forStatus: .normal)
}
```

Big thanks @matt

Comment: What if you put `ConnectionOn` instead of `Connection/ConnectionOn` as image name?

Comment: Yeah, added now screenshot of Assets.
Edit: Screenshoted ConnectionOff but same problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
let mvc = MainViewController()
```

Think about what the phrase `MainViewController()` does! It *creates a new separate second instance* of MainViewController. Thus the view never loads from the storyboard, the outlet to the button is never hooked up, and you crash.

What you want is a reference to the actual MainViewController instance whose view already exists in your interface. That is the one with the button you can see.

> In my MainViewController it works

Yes, because in MainViewController you know how to get a reference to this instance — you just say `self`. But even there it wouldn’t work if you said `MainViewController()`.

> It seems that RandomClass has no access to assets.xcassets because it doesnt find the name of the image?

Yes it does. It finds the image. What is nil is the *button*.

Comment: Okay I understand the problem, but I don't know how to fix this issue. Looked in other posts but I can't reach a working reference. Can u give me a hint? Of course I want to find a solution on my own but don't know how to start

Comment: I do not know where your real MainViewController is, within your view controller hierarchy. Only you know that. Using that knowledge, you can write an expression that gets a reference to it through the view controller hierarchy. I give an example of figuring it out, here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECinstanceRefs The mistake you are making is the same as in my "legal but stupid" code comment. My discussion describes one particular case; but you need to figure out the right expression given your actual view controller hierarchy and the MainViewController's place within it.

Comment: Thank you so much!